# Redirect system or child process standard output in linux fedora

Tags: linux, stdout

When exicuting a command in linux the program will return status text before returning what i want even with grep

for example:

```
[12:06:44.061] started
[12:06:44.062] Everything is ok
[12:06:44.201] Exiting
123123123123
```

all i want is the 123123123 to return, i want to surpress the time stamps before it.
even if i go `./someprogram | grep ^ID: | awk '{print $2}'` it still shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing to stderr. Use `./someprogram 2>&1 | grep ...`

The `2>&1` redirects stderr (filehandle 2) to the location of stdout (1).

See `man bash`, specifically the section about output redirection, for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
./someprogram | grep -v "^\["
```